# How to style divs to behave like table cells?

Tags: html, css

How to style divs with ids 1&2 and the inner divs to behave like a table?I mean that the first column is for label, second is for input and the third is for button.  I've tried to fix inner divs' width, but it has not worked for me, it's just stayed the same.(All inner divs are displayed inline)

```
<div id='1'>
    <div><h4></h4></div>
    <div><select></select></div>
    <div><button></button></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id='2'>
        <div><h4></h4></div>
        <div><input></input></div>
        <div><button></button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) : table-cell -> Let the element behave like a <td> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any CSS code. Add a class of `.table-cell` to the divs that need to behave as cells and add this CSS (internal or external CSS).

```
div.table-cell {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can make your HTML structure behave like a table, by adding the following CSS.

```css
#div1, #div2{ display:table; }
#div1 div, #div2 div{ display:table-cell;}
```